# Замена домена отправителя email через Exim

Tags: ubuntu, exim

У меня системные письма отправляются с адресом отправителя `login@server1`.
`server1` - это имя хоста (`/etc/hostname`).

Сделал это в хардкорном режиме в `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template` в секции `begin rewrite` правилом `login@server1 login@domain.tld`. Это работает.

Как написать правило:

- что бы вместо `server1` указать файл `/etc/hostname`
- что бы вместо `domain.tld` указать поиск из файла `/etc/email-addresses`

В `/etc/email-addresses` будет добавлена строка `server1:domain.tld`.

Comment: если вы хотите подмену домена организовать (в проходящих через вас сообщениях) через значения в `/etc/email-addresses`, то при чём тут вообще `/etc/hostname`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. если вы хотите просто подменять один домен на другой в проходящих через ваш *exim* сообщениях, то `/etc/hostname` тут вообще ни при чём.
2. лучше не менять уже устоявшейся семантики файла (`/etc/email-addresses`), а воспользоваться другим. ну, например, `/etc/domain-addresses`.

вносите в него подмену. например:

```
$ cat /etc/domain-addresses 
mu:bumbum
```

добавляете правило подмены. что-нибудь вроде:

```
*@* "${lookup{${domain}}lsearch{/etc/domain-addresses} {$1@$value}fail}" Ffrs
```

третье поле — это [флаги, указывающие, в каких именно заголовках](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-address_rewriting.html#SECID154) надо делать подмены.

и проверяете:

```
$ /usr/sbin/exim -brw a@mu
  sender: a@bumbum
    from: a@bumbum
      to: a@mu
      cc: a@mu
     bcc: a@mu
reply-to: a@bumbum
env-from: a@bumbum
  env-to: a@mu
```

Comment: все верно. отлично работает. благодарю.